# How to upload file from micro control to a tomcat servlet

Tags: tomcat, file-upload

I have a micro-controller that I would like to upload a file from to a java servlet running under tomcat.  The servlet part is working fine when uploading from a browser, but I'm struggling with uploading a file from my micro controller.

Two questions:

1 - From tomcat how can I look at the raw post statement.  Ive tried several renditions of the input filters including the Requestdumperfilter - but they all want to help me and format the data - I need the raw data.

2 - I'm testing with the upload post that was in the servlet demo.  I keep getting 
 org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found - but clearly the boundaries are defined.

```
POST /Download/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; 
boundary=---------------------------263081694432439
Content-Length: 441
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Data from sample file
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="destination"

/tmp
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"

Upload
-----------------------------263081694432439--
```

Comment: There should be an empty line between the headers and the body.

Comment: by header and body - I assume you mean the first line.  I do have that, but guess I didn't copy when I did the post.

Answer (score 0):

Your boundary has to be in the content type header.
Also there should be an empty line between the http headers and the request body.
Your headers end at `Content-Length: 441` but the first new line is after `Content-Type: text/plain` and the parser expects the boundary at the beginning of the body but finds`Data from sample file`.

```
POST /Download/upload HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------263081694432439
Content-Length: 422

-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

Data from sample file
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="destination"

/tmp
-----------------------------263081694432439
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"

Upload
-----------------------------263081694432439--
```

Comment: Well, this works.  Not sure of all the specs.  Example - line 3, boundary has to be on this line rather then new line.